# Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Add_Numbers': The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, jna

I am using JNA to call .Net method from java, it is able to load the .dll file but it can not call the method. And there are no spell mistakes and it loading .dll file fine. I am getting the error: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Add_Numbers': The specified procedure could not be found.**

> Public Function Add_Numbers(ByVal no1 As Integer, ByVal no2 As
>   Integer) As Integer

is a method from .Net (.dll) can any one help me..

This is the java code

```
public interface Image_Capture extends Library {
        Image_Capture INSTANCE = (Image_Capture) Native.loadLibrary("D:\\Test_DLL", Image_Capture.class);
        int Add_Numbers(int a,int b);        
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Image_Capture sdll = Image_Capture.INSTANCE;       
        int result=sdll.Add_Numbers(10,20);
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

This is the code in .Net i dont know the total

```
Public Function Add_Numbers(ByVal no1 As Integer, ByVal no2 As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: Post the source code for both the files---Java as well as .NET source files!

Comment: @shekhar suman i have added the java code check it once

Comment: Run [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) on the DLL to see the actual name of the exported function you're looking for.

Comment: As technomage said, use Dependency Walker it's more likely that the name of the function you're trying to call isn't exactly "Add_Numbers"

Comment: JNA can only call C functions as exports from a DLL, it cannot call .NET methods.